# Using Openjdk in FireFox on Mac OS X 10.5.8

Tags: macos, java, osx-leopard, powerpc, openjdk

I've got an old PowerMac G5, and I found openjdk7 binaries for my mac! This is great. Now is there a way to use this version of java in a browser like Firefox or TenFourFox, so I can use web apps that require a java greater than 5 ? I am running 10.5.8

Answer (score 0):

Nope, sorry.

(1) TenFourFox doesn't support binary plugins anymore.  Their reasoning is that any plugin version old enough to still run on PPC mac is probably so old that it hasn't been patched against any "recent" security vulnerabilities.

(2) OpenJDK initially ran only in command-line mode and in X11 graphic mode.  Their port to Mac-native graphics mode ("Aqua", "Cocoa", "CoreGraphics") is still incomplete:
 https://wikis.oracle.com/display/OpenJDK/Detailed+Cocoa-AWT+Status